# Failing to copy contents of an array of strings(a double char pointer returned from a function) into another array of strings? (C)

Tags: c, c-strings

The function:

```
#define MAX_MATCHES 10
#define BUFFER_SIZE 100

char **search_regex(const char *string, const char *regex) {
    regex_t preg;
    int rv;
    size_t nmatch = MAX_MATCHES;
    regmatch_t pmatch[MAX_MATCHES];
    char **matches = malloc(MAX_MATCHES * sizeof(char *));

    // Compile the regular expression
    rv = regcomp(&preg, regex, REG_EXTENDED);
    if (rv != 0) {
        char error_message[BUFFER_SIZE];
        regerror(rv, &preg, error_message, BUFFER_SIZE);
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex '%s': %s\n", regex, error_message);
        return NULL;
    }

    // Match the regular expression against the string
    rv = regexec(&preg, string, nmatch, pmatch, 0);
    if (rv == 0) {
        // The regular expression matched. Extract the matched substrings and store them in the matches array.
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < MAX_MATCHES; i++) {
            if (pmatch[i].rm_so == -1) {
                // No more matches
                break;
            }
            int start = pmatch[i].rm_so;
            int end = pmatch[i].rm_eo;
            int length = end - start;
            matches[i] = malloc((length + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strncpy(matches[i], &string[start], length);
            matches[i][length] = '\0';
        }
    }

    // Free the regular expression
    regfree(&preg);
    return matches;
}
```

How do I copy it into an array of strings declared in main like

```
char hold[3][100];

memcpy(hold, search_regex(...,...),sizeof(char*)*10);
```

How do I maneuver through this as this is an elementary problem of a program I am developing...
I have used tried using strcpy iteratively but to no avail

Comment: If you want to copy n strings, then use a loop and call `strcpy` n times.

Comment: `char hold[3][100];` is an actual 2-dimensional array.  No matter what you have been told, `char **search_regex()` does **not** return an actual 2-dimensional array.  It returns a **pointer** to a **one**-dimensional array of **pointers** to individual and completely separate **one**-dimensional arrays of `char`.  You can't use a single, simple `memcpy()` to copy from one to another.

Comment: I want a function which returns a list of matched regex substrings; I want to store that result in an array of strings; how do I do that?